# why does driver.current_url throw error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = { "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2 }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
print(url, driver.current_url)
```

> File
>   "/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 491, in current_url
>       return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 234, in execute
>       response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)   File
>   "/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py",
>   line 408, in execute
>       return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py",
>   line 440, in _request
>       resp = self._conn.getresponse()   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line
>   1331, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line
>   297, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line
>   266, in _read_status
>       raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"

PS: Chromedriver is in current directory

**Updates added from The discussion:**

I think I get my problem I am printing the pair, url and current_url several times, to see if it is able to figure out the redirected url. Till the redirect happens it prints identical thing but breaks when redirects. – ishandutta2007 16 hours ago

yes chrome is opening, if I don't print driver.current_url it silently goes to the redirected url . But I need the redirected url. So now I caught this exception gave a long sleep and then did driver.current_url again when the page totally settles down, still it throws the error. – ishandutta2007 16 hours ago

Comment: You left out a pretty important part - what's `url`?

Comment: a string. Be assured that its a valid value as I can see the page open right in front of me.

Comment: Just curious if there's something on the website itself that's causing Chromedriver to close the connection - you may have some luck looking in the Chromedriver logs. does the behavior persist in firefox?

Comment: I think I get my problem I am printing the pair, url and current_url several times, to see if it is able to figure out the redirected url. Till the redirect happens it prints identical thing but breaks when redirects.

Comment: can you sidestep the issue by going directly to the redirected URL? monitor the web traffic going on thru the redirect via the Network tab in Dev tools, and try and replicate it if possible. sometimes it's easier to handle those things w/ `requests` too, but depending on your use case that may not be an option.

Comment: is chrome opening or not?

Comment: yes chrome is opening, if I don't print `driver.current_url` it silently goes to the redirected url . But I need the redirected url. So now I caught this exception gave  a long sleep and then did `driver.current_url`  again when the page totally settles down, still it throws the error.

Comment: another issue I am seeing is any opertion on driver object post redirection throws `[Errno 61] Connection refused`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: the other problem mentioned is an effect, not a separate problem.